# Cyclotomic extension over Q special case of Kronecker Weber theorem.

Tags: galois-theory

For $d\in\mathbb{Q}$, how could one show that $Q(\sqrt{d})$ lies in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ without using the [Kronecker-Weber theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem)?

Comment: 1) Use the decomposition of the discriminant into prime discriminants, and show that the corresponding quadratic fields are cyclotomic using the fact that in these fields, only one prime is ramified.

Comment: 2) Use quadratic Gauss sums.

Comment: @rayjsh:  It appears you tried to edit your own question, but were not logged in-the edit comes from an anonymous user.  If you log in, I think you should be able to edit it.  I wouldn't want to put those words in your mouth if they aren't yours.